# Does Ruby's 'open_uri' reliably close sockets after read or on fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping

I have been using `open_uri` to pull down an ftp path as a data source for some time, but suddenly found that I'm getting nearly continual "530 Sorry, the maximum number of allowed clients (95) are already connected."

I am not sure if my code is faulty or if it is someone else who's accessing the server and unfortunately there's no way for me to really seemingly know for sure who's at fault.

Essentially I am reading FTP URI's with:

```
  def self.read_uri(uri)
    begin
      uri = open(uri).read
      uri == "Error" ? nil : uri
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
      nil
    end
  end
```

I'm guessing that I need to add some additional error handling code in here... 
I want to be sure that I take every precaution to close down all connections so that my connections are not the problem in question, however I thought that open_uri + read would take this precaution vs using the Net::FTP methods.

The bottom line is I've got to be 100% sure that these connections are being closed and I don't somehow have a bunch open connections laying around.

Can someone please advise as to correctly using read_uri to pull in ftp with a guarantee that it's closing the connection?  Or should I shift the logic over to Net::FTP which could yield more control over the situation if open_uri is not robust enough?

If I do need to use the Net::FTP methods instead, is there a read method that I should be familiar with vs pulling it down to a tmp location and then reading it (as I'd much prefer to keep it in a buffer vs the fs if possible)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `read_uri` and am having a surprisingly hard time finding search results. Do you mind sharing a snippet of code that requires and/or uses it?

Comment: LOL, I'm sorry.  I had written this code a few months ago and forgot that I'd defined read_uri as follows (realizing at the time I needed to add more error handling: http://j.mp/tNHpmr

Comment: Assuming that you don't run windows you could probably see what's going on from your side with running "netstat" in the command prompt.

Comment: Good idea @sunkencity, however running a few instances on heroku adds a little complexity to the scenario.  It is possible that any of 4 different app instances could have the offending connections so I'd like to be sure I'm handling the exception fully before really digging into which client may have the existing connections I think.  But I will poke around on one of the servers to see if it has zombie connections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you are not closing the handles. [OpenURI's docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/frames) start with this comment:

```
It is possible to open http/https/ftp URL as usual like opening a file:

open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
  f.each_line {|line| p line}
}
```

I looked at the source and the `open_uri` method does close the stream if you pass a block, so, tweaking the above example to fit your code:

```
uri = ''
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
  uri = f.read
}
```

Should get you close to what you want.

---

Here's one way to handle exceptions:

```
# The list of URLs to pass in to check if one times out or is refused.
urls = %w[
  http://www.ruby-lang.org/
  http://www2.ruby-lang.org/
]

# the method
def self.read_uri(urls)

  content = ''

  open(urls.shift) { |f| content = f.read }
  content == "Error" ? nil : content

  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
    retry if (urls.any?)
    nil
end
```

Comment: Okay, yes, I believe you're correct here.  I've found the same thing after poking around some.  Thanks!  I'll give this a shot and see if things calm down now.

Comment: Well, good to know it's not me now.  However I'm still getting the errors of too many connections.  When this occurs, I need to switch gears to a backup server.  How would you add an exception handler to this so if an error is thrown, try stepping into another URI?

Comment: What you could also be running into, is TCP will reserve a connection for a period of time after it has been closed, but I don't remember how long that is right now. You could be requesting too many files inside that window though, exhausting the available number.

Comment: I will also suggest you look at [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) and Hydra. Typhoeus is a great HTTP client that will provide a lot of power and control for what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are several ways to deal with the exceptions, but at a minimum you can wrap your "get" and retry with the other URL. I'll add a suggested example.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for that.  I would be curious to see some more details as well as understanding if "retryable-rb" would be helpful.  Also, you've piqued my interest in Typhoeus as I've heard it mentioned long ago and had forgotten it.  I thought I'd separate this out into another thread to allow a more clear exploration since it's starting to shift off topic.  Of course I'd like to thank you with with more credit as well for all your input here!  The thread is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706367/retryable-ftp-http-uri-reading-with-typhoeus) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood.  I had thought you'd provide an example with Typhoeus in this scenario and thus my creation of the other thread.

Answer (score 5):

Try using a block:

```
data = open(uri){|f| f.read}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The block seems to have helped.  Wish I could split answers as I can't see who posted first exactly, but since the other answer had some more details, I'm going to go ahead and assign it as the answer.  But thanks!