# Retryable FTP & HTTP URI reading with Typhoeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping

Having discussed some failure handling in "[Does Ruby's 'open_uri' reliably close sockets after read or on fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704751/does-rubys-open-uri-reliably-close-sockets-after-read-or-on-fail)", I wanted to dig into this a little deeper.

I'd like to attempt to pull data from an FTP server, then if that fails, attempt a pull from an http server.  If these both fail, I'd like to cycle around and attempt a retry several times with a short pause in between the attempts (perhaps 1 second)

I read about the "retryable" method in "[Retrying code blocks in Ruby (on exceptions, whatever)](http://blog.codefront.net/2008/01/14/retrying-code-blocks-in-ruby-on-exceptions-whatever/)", however [retryable-rb](https://rubygems.org/gems/retryable-rb) may be more robust.

Would appreciate seeing an example from an old hat at this scenario as I need a reliable mechanism in place for culling data from a couple of semi-unreliable sources I have.  As noted in the other thread, it seems that [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) could offer a robust component to this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one of those gems might be a good idea but it''s pretty straightforward without them:

```
data = nil
until data
# or 5.times do
    data = open(ftp_url){|f| f.read} rescue nil
    data ||= open(http_url){|f| f.read} rescue nil
    break if data
    sleep 1
end
```

Comment: Worked great.  Saw a logic bug in the uri builders that hung up your suggestion.